# Xcode local archive uuid is not compatible with crash report and dSYM uuid

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm having a hard time symbolicating my crash report, I uploaded it to the app store through the "archive to app store" flow, but somehow, the dwarfdump uuid of both the archive's binary build and its dSYM file is different from the one uploaded to app store after it has been released. I downloaded the dsym file from app store and it had a different uuid from the one in it's local archive that was used for the upload which is really confusing, looks like there's a difference between an archive build and a release build, so using atos is impossible as UUIDs are diferent. I can get the uuid of the crash report and the downloaded dSYM file to be the same but then they will both be different from the .app file which can't work with atos. please help

local archive uuid from terminal:

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Pro mpaxCrash % dwarfdump --uuid /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-03-16/Hubryde_\ 3-16-22\,\ 12.34\ PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Hubryde_.app/Hubryde_ 
UUID: EDFDC9BA-076F-3FF5-BB90-BD1648A7AFD3 (arm64) /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-03-16/Hubryde_ 3-16-22, 12.34 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Hubryde_.app/Hubryde_
```

app store build dSYM uuid:

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Pro mpaxCrash % dwarfdump --uuid /Users/apple/Desktop/crashes/mpaxCrash/Hubryde_
UUID: 402509E6-51A0-3803-90E2-EA5AEC73287D (arm64) /Users/apple/Desktop/crashes/mpaxCrash/Hubryde_
```

crash report uuid:

```
Binary Images:
0x102490000 - 0x10268ffff Hubryde_ arm64  <402509e651a0380390e2ea5aec73287d> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/BEFF6A47-CBCF-4E3D-B0BC-73B70F03061E/Hubryde_.app/Hubryde_
```

using atos to symblicate is impossible as they ought to have the same uuid, how do I get the corresponding .app file for the dSYM file and the .crash file